# How to match whole XML file without a specific match tag

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I have a question about xslt language in term of print a pdf file from a xml file trought xsl stylesheet language.
In details, I want to match the whole XML file to print it, but I can't do this, because it needs a specified tag, obiously.
Anyway I put a `document` tag in xml and `template match="document"` in `xsl` and it works properly.
The problem is that I can't put the document tag on every xml bill, because they are a lot and it's impossible.
Now I'll show you the code and I explain what I would do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versione="FPR12">
 <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
<DatiTrasmissione>
  <IdTrasmittente>
    <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
    <IdCodice>03466010232</IdCodice>
  </IdTrasmittente>
```

I would like to match `FatturaElettronica` from

```
<p:FatturaElettronica xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versione="FPR12">
```

to bring the entire XML content and print it, but writing

```
<xsl template match="FatturaElettronica">
```

on xsl stylesheet, it doesn't work. Is there any trick to do this?

Comment: The document node is selected/matched through `/`, any root element would be selected/matched through `/*`. As for matching that particular root element, well, its name is `p:FatturaElettronica` with the namespace `xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2"` so in your XSLT you would need to declare that namespace as well and use `match="p:FatturaElettronica"`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer,
but the problem is the the passive bill that arrive, sometimes are only  <FatturaElettronica> or <p:FatturaElettronica>, and the namespace isn't always the same.
Is there a solution?
However, how I can declare the namespace on xslt?
Thanks a lot, best regards.

Comment: Well, as I already wrote, any document node is selected/matched by `/`, any root element by `/*`. As for declaring namespaces in XSLT, it is XML so you declare it the same way you have it declared in your input document.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Happy new year, see you!!